# Disable styles of out of box components in cq5?

Tags: aem

I have a requirement to disable/remove "Bold" option of out of box component "text" in CQ5?
Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try it? And what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. 
The rich text editor can be configured based on your requirements as mentioned [here](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html#RTE%20Plugins%20and%20the%20features%20Property).

Thus, for your requirement, create an nt:unstructured node "**rtePlugins**" under your richtext widget, and then create another nt:unstructured node "**format**" under rtePlugins and add the multivalued property called "features" with values as per your requirements i.e., italic and underline.

The json for the same is shown below,

```
text: { xtype: "richtext", name: "./text", hideLabel: true, 
    jcr:primaryType: "cq:Widget",
    rtePlugins: {
        jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured",
        format: {
            features: [ "italic", "underline" ],
            jcr:primaryType: "nt:unstructured"
        }
    }
},
```